# How can one show as "active" in Facebook Messenger if it's not installed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

My girlfriend says she doesn't have messenger, but I see her as active on Messenger. Does that mean she has messenger? Sorry but I'm new to Facebook, so I don't really know these things.

Comment: How do you see her as active on Messenger?

Answer (score 3):

If she has the chat open in Facebook website (on a pc perhaps) then you can see her as active in messenger even though she doesn't have the messenger app.